# Setting an Item in nested dictionary with __setitem__

Tags: python, wrapper

Here's what I did, trying to create a wrapper for a dict-like database, among other functions:

```
    class database(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.db = anydbm.open(name, 'c')

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            key = str(key)
            try:
                self.db = anydbm.open(self.name, 'w') 
            except Exception,e: 
                raise e
            else:
                return cPickle.loads(self.db[key])
            finally:  
                self.db.close()

        def __setitem__(self, key, value):
            key = str(key)
            value = cPickle.dumps(value)
            try:
                self.db = anydbm.open(self.name, 'w')
            except Exception,e:
                print e 
            else:
                self.db[key] = value
            finally:  
                self.db.close()
```

When I try to define a new key in a dict nested within, it seems getitem is returning a value instead of a reference, so the definition is not finally modified after the setitem.

```
>>> from database import database
>>> db = database('test')
>>> db['a'] = {'alpha':'aaa'}
>>> db['a']['alpha'] = 'bbb'
>>> print db
{'a': {'alpha': 'aaa'}} //The value is not modified
```

Comment: I don't know is the question has the right title. Feel free to edit what you think best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to understand what you are doing:

```
db['a'] = {'alpha':'aaa'}
```

is equivalent to

```
db.__setitem__('a', {'alpha':'aaa'})
```

so this dumps the dict to the disk. However when you do

```
db['a']['alpha'] = 'bbb'
```

you first load the dict from disk

```
tmp = db.__getitem__('a') # except tmp is pushed on the stack
```

and then change this dict:

```
tmp['alpha'] = 'bbb'
```

This obviously has no effect on the data dumped to disk, because your object is not involved anymore.

To make this work you cannot return a simple dict, but instead you need another object that tracks changes and writes them back to disk.

Btw, you're writing [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html). It has the same problem:

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable
>   persistent-dictionary entry is modified. By default modified objects
>   are written only when assigned to the shelf (see Example). If the
>   optional writeback parameter is set to True, all entries accessed are
>   also cached in memory, and written back on sync() and close(); this
>   can make it handier to mutate mutable entries in the persistent
>   dictionary, but, if many entries are accessed, it can consume vast
>   amounts of memory for the cache, and it can make the close operation
>   very slow since all accessed entries are written back (there is no way
>   to determine which accessed entries are mutable, nor which ones were
>   actually mutated).